How to do a systematic literature review in countries without access to databases like WoS and Scopus?
I need to make a PRISMA systematic literature review on a sociological topic. To do this, I need to systematically search the major databases, arriving at a list of metadata of the academic papers (articles, book chapters) that fit the search terms. For now, the important thing is finding this metadata in a systematic way (i.e., not just cobbling together references from whatever sources I happen to think of). Finding the full-text of the papers is not (yet) the issue.
The problem is that I am in Russia, and we do not have access to Web of Science and Scopus even via my university. For example, WoS search by documents is prohibited even with VPN.
Given this, how can academics in countries like Russia complete a systematic literature review? Are there known strategies for overcoming this problem?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Talk to your local friendly research librarians.

:))))), man, you, clearly, have no clue what Russia is @JonCuster

Use another database? Google Scholar springs to mind, or Semantic Scholar, etc.

They provide poor search options (e.g. Google Scholar gives only two options - title/all fields). I have a long and specific search term so they do not work well. @Allure

I haven't encountered this exact scenario. But I've done a few systematic reviews where I have needed access to a particular database I didn't get through my institution. I have solved this through collaborations with other researchers who do have access, or by maintaining affiliations with institutions that give me access (in addition to my primary affiliation). Basically I think that you have 3 options.

You could identify other databases that are not restricted. I'm not in social sciences so I don't know of any specifically but it may be worth investigating.
You could try to start a collaboration with someone from an institution that is not in a banned country and have them run the searches. I don't know how feasible this is for you, but it would probably be the smoothest option. Honestly, if you have a search term developed and ready to go, I have to imagine that someone in your field would be willing to just run the search, export the results, and send them to you.
You can try to circumvent the block. This one is tricky and may not actually be all that realistic. Scopus and WoS both require paid institutional subscriptions to access their databases. So it isn't so much an issue of just getting to the sites and logging in (which any decent VPN should let you do). I would have to imagine that any russian emails (institutional or private) or russian payment methods, or accounts linked to russian institutions would be blocked, regardless of the current location of the user. So you would need to use a VPN to hide your country of origin AND have access to an account managed by an institution not in a banned country. The only legal way I can think of to get around this is to get your own account through institution that is not in a banned country and then use that account via a VPN.

I hope this helps.

Thank you! This definitely helps a lot and brings more clarity about the given situation.
